# Prove that the sequence $(a_n)_{n\ge 1}$ is unbounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

> Let $f(x)$ be a non-constant polynomial with integer coefficients. For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $a_n$ be the remainder when $f(3^n)$ is divided by $n$. Prove that the sequence $(a_n)_{n\ge 1}$ is unbounded.

I know that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $k\equiv l\mod n, f(k)\equiv f(l)\mod n.$ By Fermat's Little Theorem, for any prime $p>3, 3^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p\Rightarrow 3^{(p-1)m} \equiv 1\mod p$ for any $m\in \mathbb{N}$. Let $p>3$ be a fixed prime number. I think one can show that the subsequence $(a_{pm})_{m\ge 1}$ is unbounded. From above, $a_{pm}\equiv a_p \mod p$ for every $m\ge 1$. Provided that m is coprime to p, we can determine $a_{pm}$ from $a_m$ and $a_p$, but in order to get any meaningful results, it seems we'd have to prove that $(a_m)_{\gcd(m,p)=1}$ is unbounded. That seems very similar to the original question. For even more generality, I think $3$ could be replaced by any prime number and the conclusion would be the same.

Comment: Note that, as I basically indicate in $(4)$ in my [answer](/a/4789420), with your statement of "From above, $a_{pm}\equiv a_{\color{red}{p}} \mod p$ for every $m\ge 1$", the $p$ should be $m$ instead, i.e., the modular equation is $a_{pm}\equiv a_{m} \mod p$. I'm unsure if this is a typo or a mistake on your part, which is one of the main reasons I didn't just edit your question to "correct" that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right general idea, but this shows how to choose $m$ first and then $p$. First, since $f(x)$ is a non-constant polynomial, then $\lvert f(x)\rvert$ is unbounded as $x\to +\infty$. Thus, we can choose any suitably large integer $m$ so $\lvert f(3^m)\rvert$ is arbitrarily large. Then, select any prime $p$ such that

$$p \gt 2\lvert f(3^m)\rvert \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Next, have

$$n = pm \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

As you've already stated, using [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) and that if $k\equiv l\mod p$ then $f(k)\equiv f(l)\mod p$, we have

$$3^{p} \equiv 3 \pmod{p} \;\;\to\;\; 3^{pm} \equiv 3^{m} \pmod{p} \;\;\to\;\; f(3^{pm}) \equiv f(3^m) \pmod{p} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Thus, for some non-negative integer $j$, we get

$$a_n \equiv f(3^m) \pmod{p} \;\;\to\;\; a_n = jp + f(3^m) \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

If $f(3^m) \gt 0$, then $a_n \ge f(3^m)$, while if $f(3^m) \lt 0$ we have $j \ge 1$ so, from \eqref{eq1A}, we get $a_n \ge p + f(3^m) \gt \lvert f(3^m)\rvert$. In either case, we end up with

$$a_n \ge \lvert f(3^m)\rvert$$

However, since we've chosen $m$ so $\lvert f(3^m)\rvert$ is arbitrarily large, this shows that the sequence $(a_n)_{n\ge 1}$ is unbounded.

More generally, for any integer $q \ge 2$, using $q^m$ rather than $3^m$ would also work.